# Question on doing the integral for Fermi golden rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

Today in the lecture, my professor did something which confused me

> As an example, we consider the photoelectric effect, in which an
>   electron bound in a Coulomb potential is ionized after interacting
>   with an external electromagnetic field. [...] The absorption rate is given
>   by 
>   $$ \Gamma_{i\rightarrow
> f}=\frac{4a_{0}^{3}e^{2}}{m^{2}\pi\hbar^{4}c^{2}}\frac{(\mathbf{A}_{0}\cdot\mathbf{p}_{f})^{2}}{(1+(p_{f}a_{0}/\hbar^{2})^{4}}\delta(p_{f}^{2}/2m-E_{i}-\hbar\omega)
> $$
>
> This gives us the rate for a precise final momentum $p_{f}$ .
>   Typically, what we want to know is the rate of electrons detected in a
>   solid angle $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ 
>   $$
> \frac{\mathrm{d}\Gamma}{\mathrm{d}\Omega}=\int_{0}^{\infty}p_{f}^{2}\,\mathrm{d}p_{f}\,\Gamma_{i\rightarrow
> p_{f}} $$
>
> Doing the $p_{f}$ integral, we have $$
> \frac{\mathrm{d}\Gamma}{\mathrm{d}\Omega}=\frac{4a_{0}^{3}e^{2}p_{f}}{m\pi\hbar^{4}c^{2}}\frac{(\mathbf{A}_{0}\cdot\mathbf{p}_{f})^{2}}{(1+(p_{f}a_{0}/\hbar^{2})^{4}}
> $$
>
> where $p_{f}=\sqrt{2m(E_{i}+\hbar\omega)}$.

but I don't get how the integral just multiplies a term $m \, p_f$ to the first expression. I thought that the $\delta$ function replace $p_f$ with $\sqrt{2m(E_{i}+\hbar\omega)}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The delta function $\delta(x)$ has unit area, but the function $\delta(2x)$ is "half as wide" and thus has half as much area; thus you can pick up extra factors from 'how fast' you cross the peak of the delta function. The general identity is
$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{\big| df/dx|_{x=x_i} \big|}$$
where the $x_i$ are the roots of $f$. In this case the factor you pick up is
$$p_f^2 \left(\frac{d}{dp_f}(p_f^2/2m - E_i - \hbar \omega) \right)^{-1} = p_f^2 (m/p_f) = m p_f.$$